# Can't configure network interfaces Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I recently just uninstalled Network Manager and I'm trying to configure a wlan0 for internet connection while having eth0 for a multicast route. Currently my /etc/network/interfaces file looks like this:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wireless-essid ZTC-F0
wireless-key 001A70D2C61A
wireless-channel 6
wireless-mode managed
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.251.235.165
netmask 255.255.255.252
post-up route add -net 10.251.0.0/16 gw 10.251.235.164 dev eth0
post-up route add -net 232.0.0.0/8 gw 10.251.235.164 dev eth0
```

When I try to ifup wlan0 it says "NO DHCPOFFERS Recieved"
When I try to ifup eth0 it just says RTNETLINK answers: File exists Failed to bring up eth0

Can anyone help?

Comment: 1. I don't see anything wrong with your wifi setup, assuming that you are trying to set up a WEP connection instead of wpa or wpa2. Your setup seems to be extremely specific, though, so perhaps there is some setting or other defined by your wireless AP that is incompatible with the settings you hav here?

2. For your eth0 connection, try the instructions from the accepted answer in the following link: http://serverfault.com/questions/601450/dhclient-what-does-rtnetlink-answers-file-exists-mean

Comment: It's actually a WPA connection so I'm not sure what that means I should do differently and also for that link you posted is the solution that I should delete the routes manually then add them through the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

To fix `RTNETLINK answers: File exists Failed to bring up eth0` try again after flushing device: `# ip addr flush eth0`.